# Can an outbound message be send from apex

Tags: apex, callout

I have a requirement to send outbound message whenever some records are updated in bulk via batch. I would like to initiate an outbound message instead of a mail once the job finishes. Can outbound messages be send or initiated from apex

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Outbound message in the strict sense of Workflows? or just an HttpCallout to an external SOAP or REST service?

Comment: Yes.. I just need to send an outbound message to an endpoint like we do in workflow through apex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Outbound messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm) are only possible from workflows.

You can however do an [http callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_http.htm) in the finish method of your batch.

If you really want to send an outbound message then you can write the data you need in that message to an object on which you have a workflow defined that fires the outbound message.

Comment: Update: you can also call Outbound Message from Flow.